# Spyder and VS Code issue with Python

Tags: python, spyder

I have this weird issue on Spyder and also VS Code. I am complete beginner to python langauge and our teacher have recomended us to use Spyder IDE as it is begnnier friendly and it could run code in cells. Now, the issue I have with spyder is our teacher have given us a pre-written code and when I try to run it. It would not run kind of.
here is the code

```
# -StartPython.py *- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

#%% starts a new cell. Use second green triangle to run just the cell that
your mouse has last clicked in (or Ctrl-Enter on a PC or Command-Return on a
Macintosh or Menu>Run>Run Cell)
"""

#%%

def hello():

    print("Hello, world!")

#%%

def myname():

    print("My name is Bill")
```

And when I try to run the first cell i.e

```
 #%%

def hello():

    print("Hello, world!")
```

I get this in the console

```
it seems the debugger cannot resolve D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\ntpath.py
This may make the debugger miss breakpoints in the standard library.
Related bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue1180193

Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.29.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runcell(1, 'F:/virtualUniversity/Languages/Python/1st_program/_62a42c7a6447d06e53ea5693a9685b69_StartPython.py')
```

now the funny thing is when I remove `def hello():` the code would run without any problems.
same thing happens with VS code too. what am I doing wrong?? Is there some setting I have turn on or something?? oh and I forgot I have already installed anaconda.

Comment: it seems like you are working with old version of python.. pls check python version

Comment: and for spyder you need to select the path your code file on tool bar where it is located

Comment: Checked the version of python and its 3.10.0

Comment: can you show me the where where you have installed your python and a spyder..!

Comment: using mac or windows..?

Comment: I am on Windows. ALso this is the python location C:\Python3 and this is the location of spyder C:\Users\timekiller\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder

Comment: When running a function definition what you do is to create the possibility for you to call that function (execute the code that is inside the function). So, for example, after running the corresponding cell/code snippet for the function `hello` you now should be able to run in the console `hello()` and get as output `Hello, world!`. The key thing is to understand the difference between **defining** a function and **calling** a function

Comment: Thanks alot. That makes alot of sense. and that why there is a def hello() over there so we can later call it.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got the idea @user218592! Also just in case, for a more detailed explanation this could be useful: https://realpython.com/lessons/function-calls-definitions/